# audio recording, 8 or 11 khz jquery

Tags: jquery, audio

I recently used the jRecorder jquery but found it recorded at 44 khz.  I need to either take the created .wav file and convert to 8 or 11 khz or find a new plugin to record at 44khz.

Any one know of a good plugin or know how to programmatically convert 44 khz to 8 or 11?

Comment: Plugin for what?  Can you do this server side?  What are your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an open source tool called *Sound eXchange* could do the job. It's a cross-platform command-line tool so you needs some server-side code (i.e., programmatically issue external command to trigger this, of course) to deal with the wave file conversion behind the scene.

Tool's download URL:
http://sox.sourceforge.net/

After the wav file is uploaded by jRecorder onto the server directory, it's ready to be converted by using server-side code. You haven't mentioned about the web server and server-side language you're using, so I assumed you are using PHP. So take a look at these:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Hope this helps!